# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_internalRoot')

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-dom-server

I am trying to switch the rendering method according to the env flag.  since i am much new for react needs the help to understand the correct way.  getting an error as,

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_internalRoot')
```

here is my conditional rendering code:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot, hydrateRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";


const renderDom = () => {
  const container = document.getElementById("root");
  const renderType = process.env.SSR
    ? hydrateRoot(container).render
    : createRoot(container).render;
  renderType(
    <StrictMode>
      <App />
    </StrictMode>
  );
};

renderDom();
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-shamir-ckhn8c?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extracting the `render` method from the object, and in the process you are loosing its context.

Read more about this at [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485)

---

You need to use

```
 const root = process.env.SSR
    ? hydrateRoot(container)
    : createRoot(container);

  root.render( ... );
```

Updated [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-cache-tssum9).